# Loading profile image and username in the navigation bar from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image of database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fHYB.png)

[code for database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px6HK.png)

I am trying to retrieve the profile image and username that is saved by the user during the registration process in the navigation header. Here is something that I did . At first I tried to get string **current user**  but it showed me null pointer exception then I tried with if statement and changed the child from **current user id** to **Users** , it only solved the null pointer but this didn't retrive the data from firebase.

**MainActivity.java**

```
   import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private RecyclerView postlist;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser FirebaseUser;
    private DatabaseReference  UsersRef;
    private CircleImageView NavProfileImage;
    private TextView NavProfileUserName;
    String currentUserID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (mFirebaseUser != null) {
            currentUserID = mFirebaseUser.getUid();
        }
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();



        mToolbar =(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawable_layout);
       actionBarDrawerToggle =  new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this,drawerLayout,R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
        navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
       drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
       actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        View navView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header);
        NavProfileImage = (CircleImageView)navView.findViewById(R.id.nav_profile_image);
        NavProfileUserName = (TextView) navView.findViewById(R.id.nav_user_full_name);

        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        UsersRef.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                {   if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("fullname")){
                    String fullname = dataSnapshot.child("fullname").getValue().toString();
                    NavProfileUserName.setText(fullname);
                }if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("profileimages")) {
                    String image = dataSnapshot.child("profileimages").getValue().toString();
                    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(NavProfileImage);

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Profile name do not exists...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }




                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)
            { UserMenuSelector(item);

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser == null)
        {
            sendUserToLoginActivity();
        }else{
            CheckUserExistance();
        }
    }

    private void CheckUserExistance()
    {
        final String current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
          UsersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
              @Override
              public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                  if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(current_user_id)){
                      sendUserToSetupActivity();
                  }
              }

              @Override
              public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

              }
          });
    }

    private void sendUserToSetupActivity() {
        Intent setupIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
        setupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(setupIntent);
        finish();

    }

    private void sendUserToLoginActivity()
    {
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
         loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
         startActivity(loginIntent);
         finish();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void UserMenuSelector(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                Toast.makeText(this,"Home",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_post:
                break;
            case R.id.nav_Profile:
                Toast.makeText(this,"profile",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_find_friends:
                Toast.makeText(this,"frns",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_logout:
                mAuth.signOut();
                sendUserToLoginActivity();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are doing wrong query on database. Show you firebase database structure. You have referred to `Users` node as base database reference and you are querying on another child with the same name ie UsersRef.child("Users").

Comment: i have added the firebase sturcture

Comment: try my answer below. Hope it will work.

Comment: Add this line `mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();`  up above of this line `FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing your database structure I believe that the child inside `Users` node is the `UID` of current `firebase user` and in the `Users` node if you are trying to fetch user details of current user then your query should be like this

```
if (mFirebaseUser != null) {
            currentUserID = mFirebaseUser.getUid();
        }
 UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
     UsersRef.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                {   if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("fullname")){
                    String fullname = dataSnapshot.child("fullname").getValue().toString();
                    NavProfileUserName.setText(fullname);
                }if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("profileimages")) {
                    String image = dataSnapshot.child("profileimages").getValue().toString();
                    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(NavProfileImage);

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Profile name do not exists...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }




                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: got this: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null object reference
        at mezohn.com.alfachat1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)

Comment: How can it thorw NPE. I had copied the code from your question. Just change my lines with same lines of yours rest of the keep them as it is.

Comment: FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

Comment: Add this line `mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();`

Comment: this was alredy there

Comment: Update your question with MainActicity code again please.

Comment: Add this line `mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();` up above of this line `FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();`

Comment: hey thanks the app worked .. the name also changed to the provided name by the user  but i got the default  image

Comment: ok now check  the value of `image` inside `Picasso.load(image)`. And make sure you are saving complete url of profile image in database.

Comment: what should be there

Comment: replace your `Picasso.load()` with this lines `Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(NavProfileImage);`

Comment: i think image has no url value. did you tried replacing picasso lines? see my previous comment.

Comment: i solved it  .. Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(NavProfileImage);

Comment: yeah that should be `profileimage` not `profileimages`. Am glad you found it

Comment: brother my app crashed when the user logs out and send me error on:                          UsersRef.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

Comment: that is because firebase user becomes null once user gets logged out. You need to reesend the user to login page if `FirebaseUser` is null.

Answer (score 1):

I use the glide for loading images from firebase. It would be something like this:

```
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

UserModel userModel = new UserModel;

Glide.with(YourActivity.this)
  .load(userModel.getUser_image())
  .into(user_image);
```

For more info please look at the [github repository](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Comment: is there any dependencies for glide??

Comment: Yes, you just need to use glide

Comment: import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;                                       https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: do i also need to add the annotation processor??

Comment: Yes you do, on the github link they explain how to put  on your project

Answer (score 0):

**At the time of register the user you should save the user's info like this**

```
                    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                userModel.setUserid(user.getUid());
                userModel.setMobile("120xxxxxxxx");
                UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                        .setDisplayName("Some Name")
                        .setPhotoUri("Phot url of the user")
                        .build();
                user.updateProfile(profileUpdates);
```

**Then when you want to retrive the image from the user's info with the other info's too....**

```
   FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
                .withActivity(MainActivity.this)
                .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.gradient_home_background)
                .addProfiles(
                        new ProfileDrawerItem().withName(user.getDisplayName()).withEmail(user.getPhoneNumber()).withIcon(user.getPhotoUrl())
                )
                .withOnAccountHeaderListener(new AccountHeader.OnAccountHeaderListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onProfileChanged(View view, IProfile profile, boolean currentProfile) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .build();
    } else {
        headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
                .withActivity(MainActivity.this)
                .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.gradient_home_background)
                .withOnAccountHeaderListener(new AccountHeader.OnAccountHeaderListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onProfileChanged(View view, IProfile profile, boolean currentProfile) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: all the things are going good from its registration till its storaege but i am just unable to get that on the nav bar

Comment: Before retrieving the user's data. The user must be logged in with some firebase credentials.  Or it will return you an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I see, you did use mAuth before initializing it! So it is returning null.

```
 FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = **mAuth**.getCurrentUser();
    if (mFirebaseUser != null) {
        currentUserID = mFirebaseUser.getUid();
    }
    **mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();**
```

Move **`mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();`** line just before `FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();` line